# Why do square numbers have odd number of divisors?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Why number like 1, 2, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49 etc has odd number of divisiors?

Comment: Any number can be written as $p_1 ^{k_1}…p_n ^{k_n}$ and if it is a square then each $k_i $ is even. The number of divisors this number has is $(k_1 +1)…(k_n +1) $ and all these factors in the product are odd.

Comment: For each $d | n$ and $d < \sqrt{n}$, $n/d$ is also a divisor. For each such $d$, there are 2 divisors, so the number of these os even.  The only other case is when $n$ is a square so $\sqrt{n}$ pairs up with itself.